# Add custom text in /post.php?post=503&action=edit

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-editor

I'd like to know how to add a custom text like "Hello world!" inside the edit post.

Comment: when you say inside the edit post can you be more specific? Are you talking about post content? Toolbars? Is it the classic or block editor? Use the edit link to improve your question and be more descriptive/specific